# fuel cms of codeigniter not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, localhost, fuelcms

I am installing codeigniter based cms FUEL CMS. I followed all the steps. 
But when I am tring to open `http://localhost/ci_cms/fuel` on localhost then it is redirecting me to `http://localhost/xxamp/` 
But if typing http://localhost/ci_cms/index.php/fuel/login then it is working

this is what i got in index.php in http://localhost/ci_cms/fuel/

```
<?php
  header('Location: start');
  exit();
```

No htaccess file here . Please advise me what I'm missing in my installion setup.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.getfuelcms.com/installation/installing

When you downloaded fuelCms after extracting. You have below folder structure

```
assets -> Folder
fuel   -> Folder
.gitignore
.htaccess
index.php  -> Fuel CMS Master Index File
README.md
robots.txt
```

Now, in your opencart structure now structure should like

```
 admin
 catalog
 download
 fuel -> Copied folder from fuel CMS
```

Now open your fuel folder replace current index.php file with "Fuel CMS Master Index File" then it works. In this index.php make sure INSTALL_ROOT will be correct. remove fuel from end.

So it should be

```
define('INSTALL_ROOT', str_replace('\\', '/',realpath(dirname(__FILE__))).'/');
```

Comment: where is the opencart  folder

Comment: You got Welcome to Fuel message? By running localhost/<project folder>/fuel ??

Comment: http://localhost/ci_cms/index.php/fuel/login is working but now how to remove index.php from url ...i followed all the steps now it becoming little bit messy

Comment: That you can do using .htaccess

Comment: now where to put this .htaccess file in  localhost\ci_cms\fuel\modules    or localhost\ci_cms\fuel\     or       localhost\ci_cms\

Comment: Inside fuel folder localhost\ci_cms\fuel\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76339/discussion-between-vipul-sharma-and-jack).

Answer (score 0):

add this to your .htaccess

```
< IfModule mod_rewrite.c >

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $0 !^(index\.php|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L] 

< /IfModule >
```

and change in system/application/config/config.php.

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your root .httaccess
then change the value of RewriteBase  to be just a slash. So it should look like this

```
    RewriteBase /
```